# Spaces between operators and numbers in textmode

Tags: spacing, siunitx, typography, math-operators

I just found the package `siunitx` which also handles the formatting of numbers quite nicely. It even allows for putting an operator before the number, which is quite practical in texts. I am not sure about the spacing between operator and number, however. See this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[per-mode=symbol,detect-all]{siunitx}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1cm}

\begin{document}
Text mode:\\
In den anderen Ableitungen zählt jeweils eine Hebung von \SI{\ge 0.1}{\milli\volt} für beide Geschlechter als STEMI-Zeichen (White H et al., 2014).

Math mode:\\
In den anderen Ableitungen zählt jeweils eine Hebung von $\ge\SI{0.1}{\milli\volt}$ für beide Geschlechter als STEMI-Zeichen (White H et al., 2014).
\end{document}
```

In the output, there is no space between `\ge` and `0.1 mV` in the first paragraph, while it is there if I use `\SI{0.1}{\milli\volt}` in math mode.

So, which version should I use to get it right? There certainly must be a rule about the spacing of operators and numbers in normal text -- is there?

Comment: Try the same `\SI` input in text and math mode :-)

Comment: @JosephWright OK, both versions look identical now, no spaces. What I meant was more like is there a rule that if you have a complete formula (even one as simple as `$a>b$`) there must be spaces in the output, and if you are using just an operator and a number in normal text, spaces have to be removed?

Comment: I think part of what may be happening in the first example is that the space after `\ge` is ignored, since it is functioning to signal the end of the command (compare with `\S A` to produce §A--you wouldn't want a space in the output, but typing the space tells LaTeX that the command is finished). If you want a space after a command, you need to force it: `\ge\ `. In math mode all spaces are ignored anyway, which is why you get the same output for both expressions in math mode.