# Spacing between relational symbol and number (not used as binary operator)

Tags: spacing, siunitx, relation-symbols

I would like to use expressions like "< 1 W" in the text to express "less than one Watt". I try to use the `siunitx` package throughout the whole document to get a consistent look.

There is the option to use `\SI{< 1}{\watt}` which produces no space between "<" and "1", so I guess this is the recommended typography.
However, I would like to do the same for, e.g., "< \lambda/2". When used in math mode this produces a space after "<" and I see no option to use `siunitx` since I do not want to write "< 1 \lambda/2".

Is there a way to achieve the desired output with `siunitx` or do I have to remove the space in math mode manually?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I don't quite understand what connection you suggest to tolerances. Maybe I'll be more specific. I work in physical optics, so here `\lambda` means "wavelength" which is also used as a unit like "we can measure to one tenth of the wavelength". So at least IMHO it's more natural to write `\lambda/2` than `0.5 \lambda`. The meaning of "< \lambda/2" should then be clear. From egreg's comments I now think the main question is if there should be a space between a (single) relational symbol such as `<`  and a physical quantity such as `\lambda/2` or `1 W`.

Comment: I apologize for misinterpretation.  I was thinking you were looking for a shorthand nomenclature for saying "less than [some value]" I will delete my earlier comment, as it misleads the reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a command for that; but I don't think your readers will appreciate.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand{\lt}{{<}}

\begin{document}

\SI{<1}{\watt}

\SI[parse-numbers=false]{\lt\lambda/2}{\watt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe my question was ambiguous. I do not want do say "< \lambda/2 W", but "< \lambda/2". So \lambda basically takes the place of the unit, but I find "\lambda/2" better understandable than "0.5 \lambda". Why do you think the readers might not appreciate this?

Comment: @CorneliusSicker Not sure I understand the connection with `siunitx`, then. I'd definitely write `$<\lambda/2$`, with the standard spacing.

Comment: I want to express a physical quantity, hence I'd like to use `siunitx` to get consistent output. If you prefer the math mode solution with the space, would you also write `$< \SI{1}{\watt}$` (producing a space), rather than `\SI{<1}{\watt}` (no space)? So maybe it's more a typographical question if the standard way of `siunitx` to typeset "< some quantity" is correct?

Comment: @CorneliusSicker If I were to use it, I'd simply type `$<\SI{1}{\watt}$`, but my mathematician's background might be kicking in.

Comment: Okay, so it appears to be a matter of taste so far. Thanks nevertheless for providing a way to achieve both versions with `siunitx`. [This question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328229/spaces-between-operators-and-numbers-in-textmode) might be related, in spite of having no answer, yet.